# How to specify controller in ActionLink html helper in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink, routevalues

I have a web application developed in **ASP.NET MVC3** with **C#** and **Razor**.

I would like to call a specific **Action Method** of a specific **Controller** by using the **ActionLink** HTML helper. I know that the second parameter of ActionLink specifies the Action Method to be called from the **Default route**, which is the only one in my **Global.asax** file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I would like to call the **Download** Action Method from the **Home** Controller instead of **Index**. This does not work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Presentation", "Download", "Home", new { topicId = topic.TopicId } )
```

It requires as third parameter a type Object but I cannot find on the web any example.

What are the steps needed in order to call a specific Controller/ActionMethod? Shall I create another route in my Global.asas file?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { controller = "Home",  Id = topic.TopicId });
```

The third parameter, object: routeValues, is used as dictionary in Asp.net MVC. Phil Haacked [blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/06/usability-vs-discoverability.aspx) about the decision for using object as route values.

**update**:
Your overload function is not working because you are calling [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx). *String is also object*. So, you are passing `"Home"` as routeValues and `new { topicId = topic.Id}` as htmlAttributes. :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it something new in MVC3? In MVC2 I remember it worked as what I attempeted to do (the overload in my question)

Comment: AFAIK, it should be the same in MVC2. :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if there is an action in the current controller with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx) the overload you require? You will need the 5th parameter for html attributes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Presentation", "Download", "Home", new { topicId = topic.TopicId }, new { name="Download" )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Whay shall I use html attributes? Your overload will just specify an HTML name attribute with the "download" value( <a name="download", ...>. Besides being useful for binding I do not see the reason to use that

Comment: Because that was this the overload that supported specifying all the parameters you wanted.  You may just be able to use null as the final parameter but I wasn't certain so I just put null.  Failing that give it an empty dictionary.